# How to write predicate to find requests that does not contains specific word with spring cloud gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to write a route definition to match requests that does not contains specific word.
I tried something like below. For example, I would like to match requests that does not contains "**test:abc**"

```
          - id: sensitiveDataPath
            uri: http://example.org
            predicates:
              - Path=/api/**, regex=^((?!test:abc).)*$
            filters:
              - SetStatus=401
```

But this matches with all paths regardless of the regex. Is there a way to achieve this in yml file?

Thanks in advance.